# Extract results from a search using selenium python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am trying to parse a specific webpage and extract the results from a keyword search.
This is the [webpage](https://www.uniprot.org/uniprotkb?query=prolyl+4+hydroxylase)
I want to be able to extract the results in a list (like ["Q9NXG6","Q9H6G9" etc].

I am unable to find the exact locator/syntax to do this:

```
For any find_elements(class_name, xpath etc), I either get 
InvalidSelectorException: invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified
(or)
selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement
```

### This is the code so far:

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

page = "https://www.uniprot.org/"

web = webdriver.Chrome()
web.get(page)
search_protein = "prolyl 4 hydroxylase"
search_tab = web.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#root > div.N8ovH > div > main > div > div.hero-header__content > div > section > form > div.main-search__input-container > input[type=search]")
search_tab.send_keys(search_protein)
search_tab.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
#print (web.current_url)
print (web.find_elements(?))
```

Comment: `print (web.find_elements(?))` is obviously not your real code.  Please edit the question and add your real code, and the full error traceback message.

Comment: Thanks. I meant I want to know what should go in place of the (?). I want to know what is the correct identifier for the collective results.

Comment: Well, how did you find the correct selector for the search element?  Can't you use the same procedure again?  What is the difficulty?

Comment: This is not a programming question.  The correct selector is "whatever that website decided to use", and we cannot answer that for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you referred to just one page, I removed the search method and instead included it in the url as follows:

https://www.uniprot.org/uniprotkb?query=prolyl+4+hydroxylase

If you need the program to use other search terms, remove the query and reimplement searching. As for getting the list, every element has `class=BqBnJ` so you can use the following method:

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

page = "https://www.uniprot.org/uniprotkb?query=prolyl+4+hydroxylase"

web = webdriver.Chrome()
web.get(page)

# let page load
time.sleep(5)

# gets elements with class 'BqBnJ'
elements = web.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "BqBnJ")

for element in elements:
    print(element.text)

web.close()
```

This will produce the following list:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. This is exactly what I was looking for. Can you please explain how/where you found the class BqBnJ. What is the rationale? Thank you again.

Comment: @Vidyaramanan For this particular example, go to the webpage and hover over one of the Entires; right-click, and then click Inspect on the element. This will pull up the html in the side, and you can find the Class. After looking at the class, verify that other entries use the same class. Gaining familiarity with the Inspect tool is crucial to web scraping. P.S. I'm a chemist :)

Comment: Thank you so much.  Hope I can learn from you how a chemist can become good at coding

Comment: @Vidyaramanan Haha just keep coding!